# Comparing dates in sql insert statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to insert records to a table from another using sql in access through vba. everything works but I want a field that contains a date to be greater than the first of the year that the user inputs.  When I added that command into my statement no records are inserted and I'm pretty sure it is because I am not comparing the date right.  I am rather new to sql so any help on this issue and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated! I have posted the statement below.

```
verifHPMS = "INSERT INTO HPMSVerified([CLIENT ID], [CLIENT NAME], [MARKET SEGMENT], [FORMULARY ID], [FORMULARY NAME], [FORMULARY VERSION],[HPMS EXPORTED],[HPMS EXPORT DATE],[APPROVED DATE]) " & _
            "SELECT DD.[CLIENT ID],DD.[CLIENT NAME],DD.[MARKET SEGMENT],DD.[FORMULARY ID],DD.[FORMULARY NAME],DD.[FORMULARY VERSION],DD.[HPMS EXPORTED],DD.[HPMS EXPORT DATE],DD.[APPROVED DATE] " & _
            "FROM " & tableName & " as DD " & _
            "Where DD.[HPMS EXPORTED] IN (""Yes"") " & _
            "AND DD.[HPMS EXPORT DATE] >= [APPROVED DATE] " & _
            "AND DD.[CLIENT ID] NOT IN(SELECT Exclusions.[Client ID] FROM Exclusions)" & _
            "AND DD.[APPROVED DATE]>01/01/" & year
```

Comment: Are the fields with the date value also of type date? Otherwise it should work

Comment: Yes they are of type date/time.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the final line with this:

```
"AND YEAR(DD.[APPROVED DATE]) >= " & year & " AND MONTH(DD.[APPROVED DATE]) > 1 AND DAY(DD.[APPROVED DATE]) > 1"
```

This compares each component of the date individually, to avoid issues with date literals and your manual method of string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the final line with:

`"AND DD.[APPROVED DATE] > #01/01/" & year & "#"`

Note that VBA and "Jet" SQL always uses #m/d/y# format for date literals, regardless of regional settings.